# How to use Reverse Relations in Model Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-model-field

Here I'm trying to create 4 Foriegn Keys of DeviceException Table in DeviceControlPolicy Table for individual Device.

> This DeviceException table will consist 4 Type of Device Exceptions
> and i am creating individual Columns as foriegn key in the
> DeviceControlPolicy Table for the each Device, just to make it easy.
> [if any suggestion please let me know how can i use this] and how can
> i solve this error

DeviceControlPolicy.py

```
from django.db import models
from .src.models.Vendor import Vendor
from .src.models.DeviceException import DeviceException


class DeviceControlPolicy(models.Model):
    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    usb_storage_device = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    usb_storage_except = models.ForeignKey(DeviceException, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cd_dvd = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    portable = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    portable_except = models.ForeignKey(DeviceException, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wifi = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    bluetooth = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    webcam = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    webcam_except = models.ForeignKey(DeviceException, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    serial_port = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    serial_port_except = models.ForeignKey(DeviceException, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    usb_port = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    local_printer = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    network_share = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    card_reader = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    unknown_device = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

DeviceException.py

```
from django.db import models
from .src.models.Vendor import Vendor
from .src.models.DeviceClassification import DeviceClassification


class DeviceException(models.Model):
    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    classification = models.ForeignKey(DeviceClassification, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    exception_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    action = models.CharField(default="allow", max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Error I'm Facing:

> ERRORS: DeviceControlPolicy.portable_except: (fields.E304)
> Reverse accessor for 'DeviceControlPolicy.portable_except'
> clashes with reverse accessor for
> 'DeviceControlPolicy.usb_storage_except'.
> HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'DeviceControlPolicy.portable_except' or
> 'DeviceControlPolicy.usb_storage_except'.
> DeviceControlPolicy.usb_storage_except: (fields.E304)
> Reverse accessor for
> 'DeviceControlPolicy.usb_storage_except' clashes with
> reverse accessor for
> 'DeviceControlPolicy.portable_except'.
> HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'DeviceControlPolicy.usb_storage_except' or
> 'DeviceControlPolicy.portable_except'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error makes complete sense, you have to give some `related_name` whatever you want, you should add or change it, so that it will not clash with other ForeignKeys.

If you don't specify a `related_name`, Django automatically creates it by using the `ModelName` as a prefix and  `_set` as a suffix..

Try this:

`Models.py:`

```
class DeviceControlPolicy(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    usb_storage_device = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    usb_storage_except = models.ForeignKey(
        DeviceException, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='usb_storate')
    cd_dvd = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    portable = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    portable_except = models.ForeignKey(
        DeviceException, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='portable_except')
    wifi = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    bluetooth = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    webcam = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    webcam_except = models.ForeignKey(
        DeviceException, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='webcam_except')
    serial_port = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    serial_port_except = models.ForeignKey(
        DeviceException, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='serial_port_except')
    usb_port = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    local_printer = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    network_share = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    card_reader = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")
    unknown_device = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="allow")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In the above example, I've added `related_name` to every column which associates with Foreignkey of `DeviceException` model.

You can change `related_name` according to your wish.